# How do I specify a range of unicode characters

Tags: regex, unicode, python-2.x

How do I specify a range of unicode characters from `' '` (space) to `\u00D7FF`?

I have a regular expression like `r'[\u0020-\u00D7FF]'` and it won't compile saying that it's a bad range. I am new to Unicode regular expressions so I haven't had this problem before.

Is there a way to make this compile or a regular expression that I'm forgetting or haven't learned yet?

Comment: It compiles fine here (2.6.5)

Comment: You're right - that does compile - I had assumed that was the portion of the regular expression I was working on that was having problems. I'll post the part that's causing me issues.

Comment: Retagged this, as answers given here explain 2.x-specific behaviour that is considerably different in 3.x. In Python 3.x, the example is correctly parsed as a range that includes the literal character `F`, as well as anything between `' '` (space) and `'\xd7'` (which means the same as `'\u00d7'`. If the question was "why doesn't the range go up to Unicode code point 0xd7ff?", that is because the `\u` escape sequence uses **exactly four** hex digits, and `\U` uses **exactly eight** - that has *nothing to do with regex whatsoever*.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The syntax of your unicode range will not do what you expect.

1. The raw `r''` string prevents `\u` escapes from being parsed, and the regex engine will not do this. The only range in this set is `[0-\]`:

   ```
   >>> re.compile(r'[\u0020-\u00d7ff]', re.DEBUG)
   in
     literal 117
     literal 48
     literal 48
     literal 50
     range (48, 117)
     literal 48
     literal 48
     literal 100
     literal 55
     literal 102
     literal 102
   ```
2. Making it a Unicode literal [causes `\u` parsing while leaving other backslashes alone](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-17) (although that’s not a concern here), but the leading zeroes are messing it up. The syntax is `\uxxxx` or `\Uxxxxxxxx`, so it’s parsed as "`\u00d7`, `f`, `f`".

   ```
   >>> re.compile(ur'[\u0020-\u00d7ff]', re.DEBUG)
   in
     range (32, 215)
     literal 102
     literal 102
   ```
3. Removing the leading zeroes or switching to `\U0000d7ff` will fix it:

   ```
   >>> re.compile(ur'[\u0020-\ud7ff]', re.DEBUG)
   in
     range (32, 55295)
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much - I had no idea about all the unicode stuff. So, it has to be 4 digits with the lower case 'u' and 8 with the upper case 'U', right?

Comment: Note this answer is made in the context of Python 2. In Python 3, there is no difference between `r"example"` and `ur"example"`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Python 2.x, you should make sure you're specifying a unicode string (with u'', or the "unicode" built-in):

```
>>> r = re.compile(u'[\u0020-\uD7FF]')
>>> r.search(u'foo \uD7F0 bar')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7084950>
r.search(u' ')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7084b48>
```

Using raw strings (as you are, with r'') gives you the (ascii) string composed by "backstroke" + the letter "u" plus the number 0 plus...

Comment: Do you need the '0' characters when the \u isn't quite long enough to be 4 long? Like for a space, you'd only have \u20 but you'd have to write \u0020?, right?

Comment: I see you've already been answered, but yeah, that's right :)

Comment: What about **full Unicode**?  For example, the Gothic block runs from U+10330 GOTHIC LETTER AHSA through U+1034A GOTHIC LETTER NINE HUNDRED but also includes the next five code points, currently unnamed?  How do you in Python express what other programming languages allow you to use `\p{Gothic}`, `\p{Script=Gothic}`, `\p{InGothic}`, or `\p{Block=Gothic}` for?  For example, in Perl, `/\pN/ && /\p{InGothic}/` yields U+10341 GOTHIC LETTER NINETY and U+1034A GOTHIC LETTER NINE HUNDRED. That doesn't work in Python, though; why not?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can use an uppercase U for larger codepoints, padding to 8 hexadecimal digits. For instance, in your example of  U+10330 you'd use u'\U00010330'

Comment: @tchrist `That doesn't work in Python, though; why not?` The Python `re` module has never handled Unicode particularly well, although the third party regex library (https://pypi.org/project/regex/) works fine.