# How to include Non-ascii characters in regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have a text file, which I'm reading line by line. In each line, if there are special characters, then I'm removing the special characters, for this, I'm using the help of regular expressions.

```
fh = open(r"abc.txt","r+")
    data = fh.read()
    #print re.sub(r'\W+', '', data)
    new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.;,?!$]', ' ', data)
```

So, here in my data, I'm keeping only the alphanumeric words along with few special symbols which are [.;,?!$], but along with it I also want Euro symbol(€), pound (£), Japanese yen(¥) and Rupee symbol(₹). But these are not present in ASCII characters, so when I include them in my regular expression like - **re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n.;,?!$€₹¥]', ' ', data)** it gives an error message.
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file preprocess.py on line 23, but no encoding declared

Comment: What encoding are you using? Are you using UTF-8?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393843/python-and-regular-expression-with-unicode

looks like you're not encoding correctly

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170211/why-declare-unicode-by-string-in-python

Comment: A workaround might be to specify a Unicode range instead ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835917/how-do-i-specify-a-range-of-unicode-characters)).  But that might not be clean if the characters you want to spare don't fit neatly into a single range.

Comment: Please specify whether you are using Python 2 or 3. If Python 2, are you using the encoding line on top of the file?

Comment: I'm not using any encoding, i already shared the code snippet here. @TWrist

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7, and I'm not using any encoding line in top of the file. @HubertGrzeskowiak

Comment: Just be aware as was mentioned that in python3 all strings are UTF-8. If you are using raw bytes then you need to use the b' prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Unicode character escapes](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/strings.html). For example, the [Euro character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) above can be represented as `\u20ac`. The four digit number is the Unicode number, irrespective of encoding types. In an example regex, this might look like:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\u20ac]
```

Comment: I already tried doing this way, but this method is not working.

Comment: When you say it "is not working", do you mean your regex doesn't match or you are still getting the `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file preprocess.py on line 23`?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, but it is not keeping that special symbol. In output that symbol like Euro is removed.

Comment: Try using `re.sub('<regex>', ' ', data, 0, re.UNICODE)`

Comment: It's working in Python 3 BUT NOT WORKING IN PYTHON 2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the solution, but potentially a partial solution. Use this as the first two lines of each of your Python 2 files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This makes Python 2 switch to UTF-8 (unicode) mode. In Python 3 this is the default.